# Who is the mystery Star Wars character on my wall?

Tags: star-wars, character-identification

Here is a picture of some Star Wars characters. It looks like it's this [wallpaper](https://www.grahambrown.com/au/star-wars-film-wallpaper/70-453.html).

**Who is the woman on the right**?

If she is anyone at all, is she meant to be anyone, who is it most likely?

[image]

Comment: It looks like Leia Organa form Return of the Jedi.

Comment: Isn't she on the left?

Comment: The woman on the right looks more like Leia to me.  Though I suppose your follow up would be who is the person on the left then.

Comment: @NathanCooper I suspect it is Leia both on the left and right, just as i suspect we are meant to believe Luke is piloting that X-wing fighter as Red-5 even though we also see him in his jedi robes. It's clearly not a "realistic scene" the poster presents, so duplicate appearances would be my explanation

Comment: [ObWebComic](http://www.basicinstructions.net/basic-instructions/2016/6/23/how-to-decide-which-star-wars-character-you-are-most-like.html).  (I'm thinking of panel 3 in particular.)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**It appears to be Leia while she is on Endor.**

[image: Leia on endor]

The three things that stick out to me that match are:

1. The large collar on the tunic she is wearing.
2. The over the top braid she has styled (barely visible in the OP drawing, but there none the less).
3. Holding a blaster.

Comment: It's also two of the same Jawa!  /s

Comment: I find this quite difficult to believe without compelling evidence.

Comment: @Edlothiad The list of female characters is pretty short to begin with, find me another one that has that hair style!

Comment: It is not my job to find your answer, nor am I stating that you are wrong. I'm merely stating I think it is difficult to believe without truly compelling evidence. Given (as far as I can tell from the OPs link) it's a licensed Lucasarts poster, there are likely details about the poster from the artist or Lucasarts somewhere, that would be an example of compelling evidence

Comment: Uh...does it count that this is a drawing of Carrie Fisher? Does that carry any evidentiary weight?

Comment: Agreed with @ChrisB.Behrens; that's definitely Carrie Fisher.

Comment: Note that her hair even has the right ribbons in it.

Comment: @Edlothiad I find your lack of faith disturbing